# Map as.numeric to only specific columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have some data in the format below, where all columns are of type `chr`.

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   id    age   name  income
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 1     18    jim   100   
#> 2 2     21    bob   200   
#> 3 3     16    alice 300
```

I'd like to use `as.numeric()` on only some columns. Preferably, I'd like to define a vector of column names and then use `purrr:map` to map `as.numeric()` to only those columns:

```
numeric_variables <- c("id", "age", "income")
```

How can I `map` that?

My desired output would look like:

```r
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      id   age name  income
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1     1    18 jim      100
#> 2     2    21 bob      200
#> 3     3    16 alice    300
```

Code for data entry below.

```r
library(purrr)
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
          id = c(1, 2, 3),
         age = c(18, 21, 16),
        name = c("jim", "bob", "alice"),
      income = c(100, 200, 300)
)
df <- map_df(df, as.character)
df
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map_at`

```
df[] <- purrr::map_at(df, numeric_variables, as.numeric)
df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     id   age name  income
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
#1     1    18 jim      100
#2     2    21 bob      200
#3     3    16 alice    300
```

Comment: I wonder if you can tell me why we have to use the square brackets in `df[]`? I haven't seen that before. Is there a name for the term I can google to read more about it?

Comment: @JeremyK. If you check the output of `purrr::map_at(df, numeric_variables, as.numeric)` it returns a list, by using `[]` we maintain the original dimension of the dataframe `df`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(numeric_variables), as.numeric) %>%
  as_tibble
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     id   age name  income
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
#1     1    18 jim      100
#2     2    21 bob      200
#3     3    16 alice    300
```

Or more easily

```
df %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `map`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
   map_if(names(.) %in% numeric_variables, as.numeric) %>%
   bind_cols
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     id   age name  income
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
#1     1    18 jim      100
#2     2    21 bob      200
#3     3    16 alice    300
```

Or if we use the compound assignment operator (`%<>%`), this can be assigned in place

```
library(magrittr)
df %<>%
   map_if(names(.) %in% numeric_variables, as.numeric) %<>%
   bind_cols
str(df)
#tibble [3 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ id    : num [1:3] 1 2 3
# $ age   : num [1:3] 18 21 16
# $ name  : chr [1:3] "jim" "bob" "alice"
#  $ income: num [1:3] 100 200 300
```